# How to reorder and include a new column?

Tags: python

Can someone help me how to solve the below puzzle ?
field1 is ordered, halo is misspelled and hence corrected as Hello and same with world and made Upper case.

[image: Have added the screen shot for reference]

```
val Input = df1[with(df1, order(filed1, field2)), ]  # Ordering first                     two columns 

val x= Input.join(Input, joinCols, "right_outer"); #creating a newcolumn

 val newDf = df.withColumn("end_ts",           (index($"start_ts"==$"filed2").otherwise($"start_ts")) 

   val output= x.na.fill("end_ts",Seq("9999-12-31:23:59:59")) # adding time constant
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I am trying to use ordering the first column and then right joining.Not able to get the desired result.

Comment: And where is the code you already have?